# Why is it that some temporal nouns cannot be marked with に? And why do they become more acceptable with には?

Tags: particle-に, time, deixis

Consider the following:

に here is used in its function of denoting the time where an event occurs (に<sub>1</sub>):

- ◯　一時に<sub>1</sub>
- ◯　一時半に<sub>1</sub>
- ◯　月曜日に<sub>1</sub>
- ◯　正月に<sub>1</sub>
- *　昨日に<sub>1</sub>
- ?/◯　昨日には
- *　今日に<sub>1</sub>
- ?/◯　今日には
- *　明日に<sub>1</sub>
- ?/◯　明日には
- *　去年に<sub>1</sub>
- ?/◯　去年には
- *　今年に<sub>1</sub>
- ?/◯　今年には
- *　来年に<sub>1</sub>
- ?/◯　来年には
- *　最近に<sub>1</sub>

に becomes acceptable if dative(に<sub>2</sub>):

- ◯　最近に<sub>2</sub>なって

Why is it that に may not be used for the instances marked with * ?
Why is には acceptable? If に<sub>1</sub> is prohibited but には allowed, does this suggest that the に of には is distinct from に<sub>1</sub>?

I think に<sub>1</sub> may not be used to mark deictic (words which meaning depends on contextual information) nouns. I think that is what they have in common. It is not possible to have useful information about "yesterday", "today", "tomorrow" or "next year" etc. unless we have more information about the current time.

Comment: I also wondered why you don't use "in" when you say "last year", "this year", "next year", "every year", "today", "tomorrow", "yesterday". (Maybe because they are adverbs. So Japanese 明日, 今年, 毎年etc. are also adverbs?) には in 明日には etc. is something like "by~~", right? And に in になって is always required because なって can't stand alone, I guess...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good observation that you mention deictic expressions. That is correct. Deictic pronouns with accusative case tend to be used adverbially rather than as pronouns; they already incorporate the meaning of `on` or `に`, so it would be redundant to have another ending. In traditional grammar, this is called *adverbial accusative* or *adverbial objective*. Latin clearly had an overt marking for this.

As for `には`, it means a different thing. It means "by", and that will not make the expression redundant.

> * on today
>   by today
>   * 今日に
>   今日には